# Why this simple bootstrap code does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-float

I'm learning Bootstrap and I wanted to make a theme from sratch but now at the starter points I'm stuck with a weird problem--icons are stick to logo at the right side of page however `float:left` with `!important` declaration must align them to the left while it does not do that!

What is going on here? How can I properly align the icons to left side and the logo to the right side?

```css
* {
  font-family: aviny;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}

.top-header {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.instagram-icon img {
  float: left !important;
  /* does not stick the icons to left side!!! */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container top-header">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="logo header" width="80">
      
      <div class="instagram-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="instagram">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="telegram">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="youtube">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Inside container div I've added a `row` div.
2. Inside the `row` created a `d-flex justify-content-between`.
3. First element (img with logo) will be placed on the right side and second element (div with instagram logo, etc) will be placed on the left side with no need to use your `instagram-icon`.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Academy</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container top-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/stackoverflow-2752065-2284882.png"
            alt="logo header"
          />
          <div class="instagram-icon">
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRb2CZZwLGcM5obAkkLvT9tEf8ptGxpJuRCYFVu4Ifjkw&s"
              alt="instagram"
            />
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRb2CZZwLGcM5obAkkLvT9tEf8ptGxpJuRCYFVu4Ifjkw&s"
              alt="instagram"
            />
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRb2CZZwLGcM5obAkkLvT9tEf8ptGxpJuRCYFVu4Ifjkw&s"
              alt="instagram"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

On css always try to avoid `!important` and dont use `float` always try to use `flex` or `grid` instead to position things.

This is Stackblitz I used: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-tqdq6r?file=index.html

Comment: Rows are already flex elements. You don't need another layer. Also, you're loading the wrong version of Bootstrap (and an _alpha_ version at that).

Comment: You haven't update the code you're showing _here_.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap rows are flex elements, so the `justify-content-between` [flex layout class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) spreads the two flex children to the sides. [Learn more about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Don't use floats. They're a dated layout technique and have very few legitimate uses in 2023.

Also consider using Bootstrap's [margin classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) instead of writing your own CSS. The `mt-3` class gets you two times the default spacing unit (2 x 0.5rem = 1.0rem), which is close to your 20px.

```css
* {
  font-family: aviny;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container top-header mt-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="logo header" width="80">

      <div class="instagram-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="instagram">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="telegram">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="youtube">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```